# using the letter h in regular expression not working?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've been at this for hours...any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to `preg_match_all` between strings, "`Level:`" and "`<HR>`"

everything works **except** when I add the letter `h`

Why?!?

```
<?php
include("courses.php");
preg_match_all('/(level:.*?)r>/i', $str, $matches); 
// this works but picks up <br>, so i wanted to add in the letter h

preg_match_all('/(level:.*?)h/i', $str, $matches); 
// i've tried changing it to `hr` but that fails, now, *even only* `h` fails

print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

I've tried escaping the h, but can't figure out what's wrong with this letter.

String is:

```
$str='Level: <B>Undergraduate</B><BR>
Information Literacy Course: <B>N</B><BR>
Special Restriction: <B>None</B><BR>
<HR>';
// this repeats alot. I just wrote it out once, but it's all in the same variable like this.
```

I think you guys asking me for the string lit the lightbulb in my head. am i not accounting for line breaks??

Comment: What's the string you're trying to match the pattern against?

Comment: Do you have a few examples strings?

Comment: "h" is a regular character with no special meaning in a regular expression. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @meagar I agree! I have to be overlooking something here..

Comment: Your regex patterns won't match `.` over line breaks, if that's what you're asking. You need the `s` modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you think it would fail, but if you want the string in between those two terms:

```
preg_match_all('/Level:(.*?)<hr>/i', $str, $matches);
// $matches[1] contains the matches
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps your string has newlines in it, in which case you need the `/s` [modifier](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to let `.` match newlines as well:

```
preg_match_all('/Level:(.*?)<hr>/is', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: !! Twice in one day ! THanks Jack

Comment: @iight I've got a weakness for regular expression problems :)

Comment: These two regexs don't seem to work with the supplied example.